# I have 6 input files that each generate 31 output files, all having the same name. How can I design a loop to send the output to specific directories?

Tags: gnuplot

To give more detail. I have three distinct input files named `total.Cu.dat`,`total.Zn.dat`, and `total.Mn.dat`. Each of these are to produce 31 output files yielding the same name, for example `0-2.emf`. I would like the output files from each `.dat` file to be stored in their respective directories, for example '`Cu-emf` is the director for `total.Cu.dat` output.

How can I edit the following script to do so?

```
 #!/usr/local/Cellar/gnuplot/5.4.10/bin/gnuplot
 ### Batch create EMF files from multiple subblocks

     set terminal emf font "{/:Bold}Sans,25"
     set terminal emf size 850,530
     set border 15 front linecolor rgb "black"  linewidth 3.000 dashtype solid
     set format x "%.1f"
     set format y "%.1f"
     set nokey
     set key top right outside reverse
     set key font "{/:Bold,15}"
     set xrange [0:1.23]
     set yrange [-2.2:2.2]
     set xlabel "U (V vs. RHE)"
     set xlabel  offset character 0,0.6,0 font "{/:Bold},23"
     set ylabel "{/Symbol D}G (eV)"
     set ylabel  offset character 1.0, 0, 0 font "{/:Bold},23"
     set xtics nomirror font "{/:Bold},24"
     set ytics nomirror font "{/:Bold},24"
     myFileOut(s) = sprintf("%s.emf",s)


PATH = '/Users/cb/Desktop/DAC-phase/3d-TM/Cu-emf/'
FILES = '/Users/cb/Desktop/DAC-phase/3d-TM/total.Cu.dat'


     do for [i=0:2] {
         stats FILES index i every ::::0 u (s=strcol(5),0) nooutput
         set output PATH.myFileOut(s)
         plot FILES index i u 1:2 w l lw 3 title columnheader(2), \
         "" index i u 1:3 w l lw 3 title columnheader(3), \
         "" index i u 1:2 w l lw 3 title columnheader(4)
}
 set output
```

I believe this may become some type of nested loop as the current loop produces the 31 output files but I really am not sure how. Thanks in advance for any help

The data set below is what is used

```
"potential" "Bare" "1/2ML OH Fe" "1/2ML OH Cu"  "0-5"
0.00           0         0.649      0.000        
1.23           0        -0.581      0.000        


"potential" "Bare" "1/2ML OH Fe"    "1/2ML OH Cu" "0-9"
0.00           0         0.297         0.000                        
1.23           0        -0.933         0.000                     


"potential" "Bare" "1/2ML OH Fe" "1/2ML OH Cu"  "1-3"
0.00           0        -0.275        0.000        
1.23           0        -1.505        0.000
```

Comment: Your script is uncomplete and data is missing, e.g. function `myFileOut(s)` is defined nowhere. Maybe you assume that data from one of your other posts should be taken. Please provide a [minimal, complete (non)working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where exactly are these 3 input files (`total.Cu.dat`, etc.)  located? In `PATH-1` or somewhere else in their own (sub)directories? Not sure if output files with identical names but with different content (just in different folders) is a good idea. What is the reason that you don't want to call the output files , e.g. `Cu_0-2.emf`, `Zn_0-2.emf`, `Mn_0-2.emf`, etc. ?

Comment: I dont want to call it because the .dat files are automatically made using another script I have and its for research purpose

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for what (I think) you are looking for.

- get all `*.dat` files in directory `DIR_IN`
- loop these files

  - for each file create a new subdirectory based on filename
  - loop all blocks in file

    - for each block create an `.emf` output file

I assume for Linux/MacOS, you have to change the backslashes (`\`) within paths to foreslashes (`/`). The latter will not work under Windows (maybe under certain conditions).

Some additional explanations:

- in order to keep the same script working for both (Windows and Linux), the line `GPVAL_SYSNAME[1:7] eq "Windows" ? ... : ...` is simply checking via  the gnuplot variable `GPVAL_SYSNAME` (type `show var GPVAL`) whether your operation system is Windows or something else and selecting via the ternary operator (check `help ternary`) the correct system command. In my case `GPVAL_SYSNAME` returns `Windows_NT-10.0` or other numbers for older systems. So, I'm just comparing the first seven characters `[1:7]` of `GPVAL_SYSNAME` to the string "Windows", (check `help substr`).

**Data:** `total.Cu.dat` located in `SO77849373\SubDir\Data\`

```
"potential" "Bare" "1/2ML OH Fe" "1/2ML OH Cu"  "0-5"
0.00           0         0.649      0.000
1.23           0        -0.581      0.000


"potential" "Bare" "1/2ML OH Fe"    "1/2ML OH Cu" "0-9"
0.00           0         0.297         0.000
1.23           0        -0.933         0.000


"potential" "Bare" "1/2ML OH Fe" "1/2ML OH Cu"  "1-3"
0.00           0        -0.275        0.000
1.23           0        -1.505        0.000
```

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 5.4.5 under Windows10)

```
### create multiple output dirs & files, from (multiple) input files
reset session

DIR_IN = 'SO77849373\SubDir\Data\'   # '' for current directory, otherwise '\' at the end
EXT    = '.dat'

FILES_IN = GPVAL_SYSNAME[1:7] eq "Windows" ? \
            system(sprintf('dir /b "%s*%s"',DIR_IN,EXT)) : \
            system(sprintf('ls      %s*%s', DIR_IN,EXT))     # Linux/MacOS

set terminal emf

do for [i=1:words(FILES_IN)] {    # loop input files
    mat(s) = s[strlen('total.')+1 : strlen(s)-strlen(EXT)]    # extract material from filename
    MAT = mat(word(FILES_IN,i))
    FILE_IN   = sprintf("%s%s",DIR_IN,word(FILES_IN,i))
    FILES_OUT = ''
    stats FILE_IN u (FILES_OUT=FILES_OUT.' "'.strcol(5).'"', 0) every ::0::0 nooutput
    B = STATS_blocks    # number of blocks
    DIR_OUT = sprintf('%s%s-emf\',DIR_IN,MAT)
    tmp = system(sprintf('mkdir %s',DIR_OUT))   # create directory

    do for [b=0:B-1] {    # loop blocks in file
        set output sprintf('%s%s.emf',DIR_OUT,word(FILES_OUT,b+1))
        plot FILE_IN index b u 1:2 w l lw 3 title columnheader(2), \
                  '' index b u 1:3 w l lw 3 title columnheader(3), \
                  '' index b u 1:2 w l lw 3 title columnheader(4)
    }
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

Files: `0-5.emf`, `0-9.emf` and `1-3.emf`

Located in directory: `SO77849373\SubDir\Data\Cu-emf`

Comment: Thank you @theozh. I currently have a. script that already makes the directories i.e. Cu-emf. by the way, I am working in Linux/MacOS (that is correct). So to modify what you have here, I keep the entire portion about set term emf and then modify the for loop to just extract the the information from the .dat file?

Comment: @CourtneyBrea is this a question? If you prefer to use an extra script which creates the subdirectories (`Cu-emf` etc.) then you simply have to skip the line with `mkdir`.

Comment: alright I will do that and yes it was a question. I dont have familiarity with some things in this script but I will figure it out :) @theo

Comment: @CourtneyBrea please ask, if you don't understand a line. For example, extracting the material from the filename could also be done more generally (i.e. characters between the first and second `.` ) like that: `mat(s) = s[_c=strstrt(s,'.')+1 : _c+strstrt(s[_c:],'.')-2]`.

Comment: I think it might be easier if I modify what I have and then post it, is that okay to do?

Comment: @CourtneyBrea well, of course you can do that, but I thought I have provided a working solution to your question and now you want to change the question? Looks like an iterative process ;-)

Comment: lol it seems so. Im trying to learn a few things at one time. I appreciate your patience. I wanted to adjust it to accommodate the some of the changes you've provided but I need to figure out how to use the FILES_IN = GPVAL [1:7] section, can you explain what  the [1:7] are for? is that relating to the number of input files?